# airflow2.0 with KubernetesPodOperator: TemplateNotFound

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x, kubernetespodoperator

I am using Airflow2.0 with `KubernetesPodOperator` want to run a command that use as a parameter a file from inside the image ran by the Operator. This is what I used:

```
KubernetesPodOperator(
    namespace=commons.kubernetes_namespace,
    labels=commons.labels,
    image=f"myregistry.io/myimage:{config['IMAGE_TAG']}",
    arguments=[
        "python",
        "run_module.py ",
        "-i",
        f'args/{config["INPUT_DIR"]}/{task_id}.json'
    ],
    name=dag_name + task_id,
    task_id=task_id,
    secrets=[secret_volume]
)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: args/airflow2test/processing-pipeline.json
```

The image does not use any macros.

Anyone has any clue? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug that started with [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/15942) released in version `2.0.0` of [`apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/).
The goal of the change was to allow templating of `.json` files. There was a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16922) about the problems it created. The bug was eventually resolved by [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17760) which was released in version 2.0.2 of the provider.

Solution:

1. Upgrade to the latest `apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes` (currently 2.0.2)
2. If upgrade is not an option use custom `KubernetesPodOperator`

There are two ways to workaround that problem one is to change `template_fields` the other is to change `template_ext`:

1st option: As posted on [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16922#issuecomment-892153152) by raphaelauv is not to allow rendering of `arguments` field:

```
class MyKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    template_fields = tuple(x for x in KubernetesPodOperator.template_fields if x != "arguments")
```

2st option:  if you prefer not to render `.json` files:

```
class MyKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    template_ext = ('.yaml', '.yml',)
```

Comment: thank you! I did try to update to the last apache-airflow (2.1.4)... but still it has not been applied the patch. 

apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==2.0.0

Comment: @salvob This issue isn't about Airflow version. It's about the provider version. Don't get confused by the similarity of the version numbering. You need to upgrade the version of `apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes` to latest version. currently the latest provider version is  2.0.2 see https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/#history

Comment: since I use the helm chart for apache-airflow directly. Do you know if, how and when will be applied the patch ?

Comment: @salvob see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#extending-and-customizing-airflow-image to add/update a pypi package

Comment: FWIW, if anyone comes across this post trying to get a `spark-submit` job running with a `json` config, the same error occurs. Need to switch over to `yaml` files to get it to work.